# T-SQL only throws error message when converting two varchars to dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to filter a query to select values that are between a given date range. My original predicate was:

```
WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-06-31'
```

When I did this, I got the error message, "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." I then tried multiple variants of the statement:

```
WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2016-7-1 00:00:00.000', 103) 
                    AND CONVERT(datetime, '2017-6-31 00:00:00.000', 103)

WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-7-1', 103) 
                    AND CONVERT(date, '2017-6-31', 103)

WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN CONVERT(date, '2016-7-1', 101) 
                    AND CONVERT(date, '2017-6-31', 101)

WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN CAST('2016-7-1' AS date) 
                    AND CAST('2017-6-31' AS date)
```

But every one gave me the same error message.

Then, just for the heck of it, I tried this:

```
WHERE [TheDate] > CAST('2016-7-1' AS date)
```

And Presto - it worked. So then I tried this:

```
WHERE [TheDate] > CAST('2016-7-1' AS date)
AND [TheDate] < CAST('2017-6-31' AS date)
```

And got the error message again. I continued to try multiple variants, but the upshot is this:

1. If I use `CAST` or `CONVERT` on two `varchar` columns to convert them to `date` or `datetime`, I get the error message, regardless of my syntax, function selection, etc.
2. If I use `CAST` or `CONVERT` on one `varchar` column to convert it to a `date` or `datetime`, the conversion works without a problem

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `June 31` isn't a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been mentioned, june 31 is not a valid date.

Here you can see how to find last date of current month

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

```
----Last Day of Previous Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
LastDay_PreviousMonth
----Last Day of Current Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
LastDay_CurrentMonth
----Last Day of Next Month
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+2,0))
LastDay_NextMonth
```

just replancing getdate() with your date will give you last day, in your case

```
declare @iniDate date
declare @endDate date

set @iniDate='2016-07-01'
set @endDate= DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@iniDate)+1,0))

WHERE [TheDate] BETWEEN @iniDate AND @endDate
```

Comment: Thanks Horaciux. I was just working on another query that also needed  a date range in the predicate, and this time I realized what an idiot I was being. And thanks as well for the above code - that's actually a better way to get the dates I need anyway.